# REACT - How can I edit the user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Making a CV creator and I've added a popup form for users to input data and then render to the page. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to reopen the popup with already submitted data for editing however, been hours of googling and no closer to having any idea what to do

the main work code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import CreateItems from './CreateItems'

class Work extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
          };
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this); 
        this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    }

    addItem(e) {
        var newItem = {
            title: this.title.value,
            company: this.company.value,
            location: this.location.value,
            date: this.date.value,
            description: this.description.value,
            key: Date.now()
          };
       
          this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { 
              items: prevState.items.concat(newItem) 
            };
          });

          this.title.value = "";
          this.company.value = "";
          this.location.value = "";
          this.date.value = "";
          this.description.value = "";
           
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
    deleteItem(key) {
        var filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(function (item) {
          return (item.key !== key);
        });
       
        this.setState({
          items: filteredItems
        });
      }
render(){
return (
    <div id = "work-container">
        <h2>Experience:</h2>
        <CreateItems entries = {this.state.items}
                     delete= {this.deleteItem}/>
    <Popup trigger={<button> Add New</button>}  modal nested>
    {close => (
    <form id = 'modal-container' onSubmit={this.addItem}>
        <span id = 'modal-header'>Add work experience</span>
        <div id = 'row'>
            <div className = 'row-segment-left'>
                <label htmlFor = "job-title">Job Title</label>
                <input id = "job-title" type = "text" ref={(a) => this.title = a}></input>
            </div>
            <div className = "row-segment-right">
                <label htmlFor ='job-company'>Company</label>
                <input id = 'job-company' type= 'text' ref={(a) => this.company = a}></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = 'row'>
            <div className = 'row-segment-left'>
                <label htmlFor = "job-location">Job Location</label>
                <input id = "job-location" type = "text" ref={(a) => this.location = a}></input>
            </div>
            <div className = "row-segment-right">
                <label htmlFor ='job-date'>Date of Employment</label>
                <input id = 'job-date' type= 'text' ref={(a) => this.date = a}></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id ='bottom-row'>
            <label htmlFor  ='job-description'>Job Description</label>
            <textarea id = 'job-description' rows = '5' placeholder = 'Describe your duties...'
            ref={(a) => this.description = a}></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id = 'button-container'>
            <button type = "submit" >Submit</button>
            <button onClick={() => {
              close();
            }}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    )}
  </Popup>
  </div>
    
    )}};

export default Work;
```

The code for creating and adding the content

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
 
class CreateItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     
        this.createTasks = this.createTasks.bind(this);
    }
          
    delete(key) {
      this.props.delete(key);
    }
  createTasks(item) {
    return <div className = 'work-segment' key={item.key}>
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        <span>{item.company} / {item.location} / {item.date}</span>
        <p>{item.description}</p>
        <span>
          <button>Edit</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.delete(item.key)}>Delete</button>
        </span>
    </div>
  }
 
  render() {
    var workEntries = this.props.entries;
    var workItems = workEntries.map(this.createTasks);
 
    return (
        <div id = 'work-items'>
          {workItems}
        </div>
    );
  }
};
 
export default CreateItems;
```

Comment: don't use refs, store the values in state instead, then you can pass the state back into the modal

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the question completely, but if you are looking to update submitted data by user, then why do you want to do it in a popup?

You can have your form in "add" mode or "update" mode and depending on what operation user wants to perform, display your form in that particular mode.
OR are you using popup to just show all entered details by user?

Comment: I just wanted to use different methods to try and learn a little more. Essentially I just want them to click a button it brings up a form and they fill it in and it renders to page. Then can click edit button to edit the inputted data. This also needs to work for multiple inputs they may have done